# PHP unset() seems not to be working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have got a multidimensional array $_SESSION['cart'] which stores items details.
I delete items from the array passing to PHP the specific item's id using ajax and I have double checked the id always punctually arrives.

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'delCartItem') {

//delete the item from the array
 $_SESSION['totItmes'] =0;
 $e=0; 
  
if ($_POST['uid']){

    foreach($_SESSION['cart']as &$arr){
         $_SESSION['totItmes'] = $_SESSION['totItmes'] +$arr['quantity'];
             
     
      
               if($arr['id']==$_POST['uid']){

                $testArriveId= $arr['id']."hello".$_POST['uid'];
                 
                  $before= count($_SESSION['cart']);
//**********************************************************************
                  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$e]);
//**********************************************************************
                 if(count($_SESSION['cart'])<$before){
                  $_SESSION['totItmes'] = $_SESSION['totItmes'] -$arr['quantity'];
                 } 
                       
               }
                $e++;
  
            }
 $_SESSION['cart']= array_values($_SESSION['cart']);

...
```

THE PROBLEM: this code works fine for the first item I delete from the basket after the Session starts. Then, it requires me to click delete and implement the whole code twice to be working and I don't understand why. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: It was a problem due to the "Add items" procedure. I don't know why, but I had to reindex the array $_SESSION['cart'] by using array_values() ALSO when I add a new item to the cart ;

`$_SESSION['cart']= array_values($_SESSION['cart']);`

In the "Add Item" procedure, it doesn't matter if I reindex it before or after the adding item code.